# Regex repeating groups

Tags: regex

I have this repeating group

```
        <Amenity>Casino</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Fitness Center</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Bar/Cocktail Lounge</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Restaurant</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Free Parking</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Outdoor Pool</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Gift Shop</Amenity>
        <Amenity>.+</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Laundry/Dry Cleaning</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Bellman</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Concierge Desk</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Room Service</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Onsite Spa</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Beauty Salon/Barber</Amenity>
        <Amenity>ATM Available</Amenity>
        <Amenity>Foreign Currency Exchange</Amenity>
```

And I'm using SoapUI's Regex assertion to ensure my XML messages contain these varying elements.

I believe this is my best bet:     `\ (<Amenity>.+</Amenity>)\`

But no luck. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: Some more information on what you actually want captured would be nice. Do you want to capture everything between `<Amenity></Amenity>` or did you want those particular listed items?

Comment: I'd like to capture everything between <Amenity></Amenity>

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In other words, this is what the regex you want looks like:

```
(?<=<Amenity>).+(?=<\/Amenity>)
```

If you're using a regex engine that doesn't support lookarounds, you can compensate for that by taking what is matched by `<Amenity>.+<\/Amenity>` and then removing everything that matches `<\/?Amenity>`.